# Undefined ProgressDialog in current activity

Tags: android

I am working on my app and I have the ProgressDialog method inside of my fragment and for some reason it saying that the acticity I am passing through to the ProgressDialog is undefined. To me it doesnt make since because im using the activityname.this which should just say you are point to the current activity, am I correct? What am I doing wrong?

```
Here is the errors i am getting
No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope   FragmentHome.java   /SideMenuTabs/src/com/begin/sidemenutabs    line 98 Java Problem

The constructor ProgressDialog(FragmentHome.DownloadJSON) is undefined  FragmentHome.java   /SideMenuTabs/src/com/begin/sidemenutabs    line 54 Java Problem

The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type FragmentHome.DownloadJSON    FragmentHome.java   /SideMenuTabs/src/com/begin/sidemenutabs    line 96 Java Problem
```

The parts that say undefined are.

The line 5 on this.

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // Create a progressdialog
    //Undefined error
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FragmentHome.this);
    // Set progressdialog title
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Testing Parse 1");
    // Set progressdialog message
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    // Show progressdialog
    mProgressDialog.show();
}
```

And line 6 on this one.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        //Undefined error
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

This is my whole fragment.

```
    public class FragmentHome extends SherlockFragment {

        private final String TAG = "Home";
        // Parse Declare Variables
        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        ListView listview;
        ListViewAdapter adapter;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
        static String RANK = "rank";
        static String COUNTRY = "country";
        static String POPULATION = "population";
        static String FLAG = "flag";


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Home Loaded");
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenthome, container, false);
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
            return rootView;

        }

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FragmentHome.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Testing Parse 1");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }



    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array 
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrive JSON Objects from the given website URL in JSONfunctions.class
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("parsingurl");

            try {
                // Locate the array name
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("rank", jsonobject.getString("rank"));
                    map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("country"));
                    map.put("population", jsonobject.getString("population"));
                    map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("flag"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: post your **actual** stacktrace and error message

Comment: Edited it and added the error codes, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AnyClass.this` points to the `AnyClass` instance in the current scope. It means that you have to be either in an instance method of the class itself or in an instance class of this class. If you are outside of `AnyClass`, you cannot access it.

From a `Fragment`, you need to call `getActivity()` to get an instance of `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try progressDialog = new ProgressDialog((MainActivity)getActivity()); if you are calling progressBar from a Fragment

Where MainActivity is your Activity

Answer (score 0):

for progressDialog() try this...

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
```